# How do i check if one of my ```LoggBockRowItem``` has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the box that my items fits in

```
function CardRows (props){
    return <div className={classes.cardRow} onClick={props.onClick}>
        {props.children}
    </div>
}

export default CardRows;
```

this is the item itself

```
function LoggBockRowItem(props){
    return(
        <CardRows onClick={props.onClick}>
            <div>
            <p className={classes.indentDate}>{props.datum}-{props.tid}</p>
            </div>
                <p className={classes.biggertext}>{props.skift}</p>
            <div className={classes.displayblock}>
               <li className={classes.biggertext}>{props.anläggningsdel}</li>
               <li className={classes.displayborder}>{props.driftstatus}</li>
            </div>
            <p className={classes.textoverflow}>{props.beskrivning}</p>
            <div className={classes.displayblock}>
                <li className={classes.biggertext}>{props.plats}</li>
                <li className={classes.loweropacitytext}>{props.rapporterare}</li>
            </div>
            <p className={classes.biggertext}>{props.rapporterare}</p>
        </CardRows>
    )
}

export default LoggBockRowItem;
```

this is the class where i think i need to check onClick if an item has been clicked

```
class LoggBockRowList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            loggbocks: null
        };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
        return{
            loggbocks: props.loggbocks
        };
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.loggbocks &&
                this.state.loggbocks.map(loggbock =>
                    <LoggBockRowItem
                    key={loggbock.key}
                    id={loggbock.id}
                    datum={loggbock.datum}
                    tid={loggbock.tid}
                    skift={loggbock.skift}
                    anläggningsdel={loggbock.anläggningsdel}
                    orsak={loggbock.orsak}
                    driftstatus={loggbock.driftstatus}
                    beskrivning={loggbock.beskrivning}
                    plats={loggbock.plats}
                    rapporterare={loggbock.rapporterare}
                    
                    onClick={console.log(loggbock.key)} 
                    />
                )}
            </ul>
        )

    }
}
```

im trying to interact with the clicked item of type `LoggBockRowItem` in the list of `loggbocks` to use and change the items value. Ive tried using the `props.onClick` inside the `CardRows` component but it dosent do anything, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Typo: `onClick={console.log(loggbock.key)}` -> `onClick={() => console.log(loggbock.key)}` so you don't invoke `console.log` immediately.

Comment: @AKX thanks im not sure why it needs to be treated like a function but now it works!

Comment: See here in the official React tutorial (search for "inline in the JSX"): https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#adding-event-handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LoggBockRowItem
  {...props}
  onClick={() => console.log(loggbock.key)} 
/>
```

or

```
const handleClick = (loggbock) => {}


<LoggBockRowItem
  {...props}
  onClick={() => handleClick(loggbock)}
/>
```

you should only bind a function to `onClick` event, other than an expression or invocation of a function

Comment: Thanks! @fengxh i didnt realise it can only be binded to functions